# Script to storage vmotion from one datastore to another

Tags: powershell, vmware-esxi, scripting, vmware-vsphere, powercli

Ive done some searching and could not find what I'm looking for so I am making a post: I would like to storage vMotion from one datastore to another, 10 at a time, and output the vm's migrated to a log file. I have this script so far that I have edited. Please let me know how to add the instructions on how to append to a log file and also 10 at a time. the -RunAsync also will not let me migrate one at a time so I may have to remove that as well. Any help?

```
# My Login Credentials

$vi_server = "X.X.X.X" # Set to your vCenter hostname|IP

$vcuser = "MyLogin@vsphere.local" # Set to your vCenter username to connect

$vcpass = "VerySecurePassword123" # Set to your vCenter username password to connect



# Connect to vCenter

Connect-VIServer -Server $vi_server -User $vcuser -Password $vcpass


# I want all old and new datastores as objects in arrays

$OldDatastores = Get-Datastore TEST-01
$NewDatastores = Get-Datastore TEST-02
$i = 0



# Get all VMs in each old datastore and move them

Foreach ($OldDatastore in $OldDatastores){
    $VMs = Get-VM -Datastore $OldDatastore

    Foreach ($VM in $VMs)
    {
        # Move the VM to a new datastore
        $VM | Move-VM -Datastore $NewDatastores[$i] -RunAsync


    }

    $i++

    # Wait timer for next migrations

    Start-Sleep 5

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get batches of 10 you can use [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with the parameters `-First` and `-Skip`:

```
$start = 0
do {
    $VMs |Select -First 10 -Skip $start | 
        Move-VM -Datastore $NewDatastore |
        Select Name |Out-File -FilePath "c:\logfile" -Append
    $start += 10
}
until ($start -gt $VMs.Length)
```

Appending to a file is just a parameter for [`Out-File`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File).

Using `-RunAsync` is counterproductive, since it causes the cmdlet to run in the background. So it would just start one batch after another and all run simultaneously.